# Converting distance to metric units with yacc/bison

Tags: bison, yacc

The input I have is not strongly formatted. It can be one of:
"about 2 1/4 miles", "1 mile 40 yards", "5m 10y".
And so on.

How can I define rules to convert this data to double values in meters? (I'm quite new with yacc/bison).

Comment: A parser seems overkill.  A list of Regexes should do as well.  But you will need to know _all_ the formats in either case.

Answer (score 0):

> The input I have is not strongly formatted.

That's a clear indication that yacc/bison is *not* the tool you should be using. It might be possible, but it will be like trying to open a box of crystal with a sledgehammer: you might be able to do it, but you will end up expending a lot of effort in manipulating a tool designed for a completely different purpose and even then you might end up with a lot of broken glass. Better to chose the right tool in the first place.

Yacc is designed to analyse an input which confirms with a clearly specified set of grammatical rules precisely and unambiguously defining its meaning. That's a pretty good description of a programming language or a data exchange format, but it's not applicable to normal human discourse. While it is true that natural language has some kind of grammatical structure, the grammar is more a set of guidelines than a rigid framework, and ambiguities and imprecisions abound.

A lot of work has been done in recent years to produce tools which can be used to attempt to analyse natural language, some of which are freely available. You might be able to find one which suits your purpose. But you'll need to bear in mind that there will always be inputs which cannot be precisely analysed, so you will have to minimise the danger of a misunderstanding.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that Yacc requires strong grammar but i was not sure. Thanks again!